# How to use node.js for an offline application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, linux

I don't really understand some aspects of Node.js. I'm working on a Project for which I need a fast and modern looking UI, therefore I'm using JavaScript with React. Additionally, I need to access a seral port on my PC so I decided to use Node.js. Everything will happen offline. I just want to read my serial port, process the data and display it on an UI. So, I managed to write a simple script which just outputs a string with `console.log()`. When executing `node script.js` everything works as expected. But as soon as I want to run anything which needs a GUI, thats not possible anymore (of course, since I'm working in the terminal). So, as far as I'm understanding node, I have to set up a http server and access it in my browser. At this point I don't really understand why node.js is neccessary, because then the script is executed by the browser (or is it?). I know that's not really a question, but I am quite confused about this and wanted to know if that's the right way to use node.js for an offline application.

Comment: The script is not executed by the browser, so that could be the right way to use Node.js for an offline application if you want to interact with it with a browser. But maybe a modern-looking UI can be achieved without web technologies?

Answer (score 0):

> At this point I don't really understand why node.js is neccessary, because then the script is executed by the browser (or is it?).

It isn't.

- Node.js runs an HTTP server.
- The browser makes an HTTP request to that HTTP server.
- Node.js executes code to determine what response to make to the browser.

The code to access the serial port would be part of that code which is used to determine the response. This *has* to run via Node.js because browsers don't provide any API that would make direct access to a serial port possible.

You might want to look at Electron.js which bundles Node.js and the Chromium browser together for a more traditional-seeming GUI application (without the usual trappings of a browser like the address bar).

Comment: Okay, so I assume the response the broswer gets is the data it should display. But this response is only made once and I want to update the data from the serial port a few times in a second. So do I have to request that data a few times in a second or how does that work?

Comment: Look into Socket.io (or the Electron.js IPC services).

Answer (score 0):

Browser environments can't (yet) read from a serial port.  So, your Node.js application is required to proxy data from the serial port to your web-based application.

Otherwise, you could create a progressive web app (PWA) and not need Node.